# Json unicode decoding in python's simplejson

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I can't decode json strings like this: "\u0e4f\u0361\u032f\u0e4f"

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> simplejson.loads('"\u0e4f\u0361\u032f\u0e4f"', encoding='utf8')
u'\u0e4f\u0361\u032f\u0e4f'
```

However php json_decode works fine:

```
json_decode('"\u0e4f\u0361\u032f\u0e4f"');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. The Python REPL prints the repr() of the string, not the string itself.

```
>>> print u'\u0e4f\u0361\u032f\u0e4f'
๏̯͡๏
```